# Boundary conditions that yields no solutions to the coefficient?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I want to make sure I'm not overlooking certain steps as I've already spent an hour looking through.

The heat equation is given as:

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
$$

The BCs are:

$$u_x{(0,t)-u(0,t)=0}$$

$${u(1,t)=0}$$

$${u(x,0)=f(x)}$$

Using the method os separation of variables I arrived at

$$\text{} X" \text{(x)+$\lambda $X(x)=0}$$

I begin first by considering case where $$\lambda<0$$
 in which we let $$\text{$\lambda $=-}\beta ^2$$

The solution to $X(x)$ is
$$X(x)=a e^{\text{$\beta $x}}+\text{be}^{-\text{$\beta $x}}$$
$$X'(x)=\text{$\beta $a} e^{\text{$\beta $x}}-\text{$\beta $be}^{-\text{$\beta $x}}$$

The BC for $X(x)$ are: $X'(0)-X(0)=0$

Substituting and substracting, we get

$$\beta  (a-b)-a-b=0$$

But observe that this does not enable us to arrive at either the coefficient $a$ or $b$ in terms of the other.

Comment: You must also use the boundary condition at $x=1$

Comment: Hint: you also know that $u(1,t)=X(1)u(t)=0$

Comment: @Chilango Did you meant to say $$u(1,t)=X(1)=0 or X(1)u(t)=0?$$

Comment: @mattbiesecker Not really seeing where this is going.

Comment: $u(1,t)=0$ implies $ae^\beta + b e^{-\beta}=0,$ so that $b=-ae^{2\beta}.$

Comment: @mattbiesecker I appreciate the help but I'm still not getting a "simplified" expression.
If my computations were on the right track, beta = 1. But this is meaningless since I want a and b.

Comment: Last comment, but then I have to let this one go.   Substitute $b=-a e^{2\beta}$ into equation you derived earlier, then $\beta(a + a e^{2\beta}) - a + a e^{2\beta})=0,$ which simplifies to $a(e^{2\beta}(\beta + 1) + \beta-1)=0.$  So either $a=0$ or $e^{2\beta} = \frac{1-\beta}{\beta + 1}.$  For $\beta >0,$ the term $\frac{1-\beta}{\beta+1} < 1$ and $e^{2\beta}>1.$  So the equation for $\beta$ cannot be solved.  Conclude that $a=0.$

Comment: This is certainly more complicated than what I was expected and what I was lectured on. But it was a good exposure.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Consider $X(x)=a\sin(\lambda(x-1))+b\cos(\lambda(x-1))$

$X(1)=0$ :

$b=0$

$\therefore X(x)=a\sin(\lambda(x-1))$

$X'(x)=a\lambda\cos(\lambda(x-1))$

$X'(0)-X(0)=0$ :

$a\lambda\cos(-\lambda)-a\sin(-\lambda)=0$

$\lambda\cos\lambda+\sin\lambda=0$

$\tan\lambda=-\lambda$

Hence for $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$ with $u_x(0,t)-u(0,t)=0$ and $u(1,t)=0$ , the solution is $u(x,t)=\sum\limits_nA(n)e^{-\lambda_n^2t}\sin(\lambda_n(x-1))$ , where $\lambda_n$ are the solutions of $\tan\lambda=-\lambda$